# Correct manner of using View- and Model-Abstracts in Joomla 3+

Tags: component, php, joomla-3.x, joomla-api

There are a lot of API changes in Joomla between 2.x and 3.x versions. 
In development of Joomla 3-components I still use the legacy class abstracts:

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');
class TestViewItem extends JViewLegacy { 
    public function display($tpl = null) {
         $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Test', 'JiwaModel');
         $model->call();
    }
}
```

But what will be the correct non legacy way of doing it in Joomla 3.x and beyond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no concrete answer for you but @george-wilson posted a answer to a similar question [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/251/when-will-the-jxxxlegacy-classes-be-deprecated/262#262).

There he says that the com_config component already uses the new MVC structure. The `ConfigViewApplicationHtml` uses the `JViewHtml` as master class. So this could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen that Jimport in any of the components in J3. The Legacy tree has been introduced to continue to use extensions built the old way. It will probably stay with us for a long time. Even when distribution packages won't provide it anymore, it will still be possible to use it.

Both JIssues and the Joomla installation are examples of using the new MVC structure. Also components like com_config use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found http://lendr.websparkinc.com/. That's a great tutorial for Joomla 3+ component development using - as far as I can see - the new Joomla 3 MVC paradigma.